# Ansible create vm machines

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Im using ansible 2.9.2. I have this playbook which works fine in creating virtual machine in vcenter from template:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
  vars_files:
            - vars.yml
  tasks:
    - vmware_guest:
        datacenter: "abcd"
        hostname: "{{ server }}"
        username: "{{ user  }}"
        password: "{{ pass }}"
        template: "{{ template }}"
        validate_certs: False
        folder: test
        datastore: "{{ datastore }}"
        esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi }}"
        validate_certs: no
        state: "{{ state }}"
        name: "{{ name }}{{ansible_date_time.epoch}}{{999| random}}"
      register: output
    - debug:
            msg: "{{ output.instance | json_query('hw_eth0.ipaddresses') }}"
```

I'm using an API and I send curl request to run this playbook. Is there any way to make it run 5 times? 
I didnt find anything under ansible module `vmware_guest` that can have like `count=5` to make 5 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the [ansible loop documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html), more specifically how to [loop over a range](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence)

Following the above doc, we can modify your first task like the following. I integrated the range counter in your instance name, adapt to your exact needs.

```
    - vmware_guest:
        datacenter: "abcd"
        hostname: "{{ server }}"
        username: "{{ user  }}"
        password: "{{ pass }}"
        template: "{{ template }}"
        validate_certs: False
        folder: test
        datastore: "{{ datastore }}"
        esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi }}"
        validate_certs: no
        state: "{{ state }}"
        name: "{{ name }}{{ item }}{{ansible_date_time.epoch}}{{999| random}}"
      register: output
      loop: "{{ range(1, 6) | list }}"
```

Introducing a loop changes the structure of the registered var which will now contain a top level `results` list for each individual loop run. So you need to change the next debug task to get the info you want.

*Solution 1*: Loop over each result and output as before:

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.instance | json_query('hw_eth0.ipaddresses') }}"
      loop: "{{ output.results }}"
```

*Solution 2*: Get all info at once by modifying your jmespath query. Note that since I don't have your data structure, I could not test the code below so it might require some tuning.

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output.results | json_query('[].instance.hw_eth0.ipaddresses') }}"
```